# Como alinhar itens da lista

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

    li:before {
      content: "\2192";
      padding-right: 10px;
    }

p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><p>Item 1 alaksjd fçalksdj fçlaksjd fçlaksjd fçlkasdj flçkajsdlçkfjasldçkjflçaksd jfçlkasjd flçkajsdlkçf asd</p></li>
    <li><p>Item 2 adflçaksd jglçakhsd flaksdh kjahsdf gjhdfjkh skjchvçz,xckhvj çzlxkcjv zçlxckjvlçz xckjvçzlxkcjv</p></li>
    <li><p>Item 3 asdlçfkj asdlkfj çalsdjf</p></li>
</ul>
```

O resultado obtido é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado desejado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Obs.: A linha vermelha é apenas para marcar o alinhamento e não faz
>   parte do resultado desejado.

É possível fazer isso via CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que utilizar o `display: inline` no elemento `p` é o que complica tudo. Como alternativa, você pode posicionar o elemento `li:before` de forma absoluta e definir uma margem esquerda para o elemento `p`. Veja:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "\2192";
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

p {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Item 1 alaksjd fçalksdj fçlaksjd fçlaksjd fçlkasdj flçkajsdlçkfjasldçkjflçaksd jfçlkasjd flçkajsdlkçf asd</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 2 adflçaksd jglçakhsd flaksdh kjahsdf gjhdfjkh skjchvçz,xckhvj çzlxkcjv zçlxckjvlçz xckjvçzlxkcjv</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Item 3 asdlçfkj asdlkfj çalsdjf</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: muito obrigado! Sua resposta me ajudou muito, e também consegui entender melhor o funcionamento. Ainda não tenho um bom relacionamento com CSS, rsrsrs... Se gostar de desafios como esse, [aqui vai mais um](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199424/como-ocupar-restante-da-section), haha...
Saudações!